# Side-Splitter Theorem, which sides are proportionally

Tags: geometry

I'm currently wondering about the side splitter theorem.

[image]

Lets say I have this triangle. Now the side splitter theorem says, that if a line is parallel to a side of a triangle and intersects the two other sides, then this line divides those two sides proportionally.

In my triangle, MB is parallel to CD and intersects EC and ED.

So the theorem states that: $\frac{EB}{BD} = \frac{EM}{MC}$.

I'm wondering if the following equation is also possible: $\frac{MB}{CD} = \frac{EM}{EC}$. This equation is used in some methods of computer science (calculate corresponding screen positions), but I'm not sure, why and in which case it is correct. Does it only work because of the right angle at C ?

Thanks

Comment: The side splitter theorem has nothing to do with the right angle. The conditions on the ratio shows that the triangles are similar, so you get other relations on the sides.

Comment: So my equation is possible, isn't it? Because of the similarity of both triangles (never thought about similarity, just "looked up" the equation and didn't thought about it)

Comment: Also known as the Intercept Theorem. A, standard, proof of this can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92929/similar-triangle-theorem-in-the-incommensurable-case/92933#92933). (This does not use an argument appealing to the properties of  similar triangles; however, the Intercept Theorem and the "Similar Triangles Theorem" are equivalent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triangles $ EMB $ and $ CDE $ are similiar, so yes, the last relation you mentioned holds.